# Mongodb simple find in php

Tags: mongodb, yii

First time using mongodb and running into something that should be simple but I just cannot get it to work. I have a Persons collection that looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "50607a9a9a3f5fd402000000"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Cool",
    "lastname": "Dude",
    "birthday": null,
    "country": null,
    "friends": [],
    "comments": [],
    "wines": [],
    "avatar": null,
    "_status": null,
    "_salt": "1d8ebb2deca53a21c4a47422ecf2ae1a",
    "_password": null,
    "update_time": 1348500122,
    "creation_time": 1348500122
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "50607aed9a3f5fd402000001"
    },
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Alex",
    "lastname": "Rodriguez",
    "birthday": null,
    "country": null,
    "friends": [],
    "comments": [],
    "wines": [],
    "avatar": null,
    "_status": null,
    "_salt": "5e751eec310808fca425537cdc8a8453",
    "_password": null,
    "update_time": 1348500205,
    "creation_time": 1348500205
}
```

Using the following code I was expecting to find the record I am looking for:

```
$person = new Persons();

$person = $person->find(array('firstname' => 'Alex'));

var_dump($person);
```

I am using the EMongoDocument class from the Yii framework I think. Just started here and am quite used to mysql.

This returns Cool Dude instead of Alex Rodriguez.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I needed to use findByAttributes();

```
$person = $person->findByAttributes(array('firstname' => 'Cool'));
```